# Use a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote some code that should save the color that is chosen by the user, saves it, and applies the changes when you click on a button, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Could someone please help me with this issue?

```js
var backgroundColor = null
var headerColor = null
function changeBackgroundColor() {
    backgroundColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
}

function changeHeaderColor() {
    headerColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
}

function saveColors() {
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    document.getElementById("h1").style.color = headerColor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Change the background color!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Change the background color!</h1>
            <input type="color" id="color" value="#1784b3"><br>
            <button onclick="changeBackgroundColor();">Save background color</button>
            <button onclick="changeHeaderColor();">Save header color</button>
            <button onclick="saveColors();">Apply changes to page</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also made a codepen:
https://codepen.io/mauro-scheltens/pen/oNBLrWV

Comment: Have you tried putting the script element in the end of the body element

Comment: That doesn't change anything, and when I put some working code in my javascript it also just works, so that is not the issue.

Comment: I get an error message running your functions. `document.getElementById(...) is null`. I can't find the element for `document.getElementById("body")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the necessary ids to the html tags:

```js
var backgroundColor = null
var headerColor = null
function changeBackgroundColor() {
    backgroundColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
}

function changeHeaderColor() {
    headerColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
}

function saveColors() {
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    document.getElementById("h1").style.color = headerColor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Change the background color!</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <h1 id="h1">Change the background color!</h1>
            <input type="color" id="color" value="#1784b3"><br>
            <button onclick="changeBackgroundColor();">Save background color</button>
            <button onclick="changeHeaderColor();">Save header color</button>
            <button onclick="saveColors();">Apply changes to page</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, you made my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems seems to be this part:

```
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

You're trying to get the body element by id, which is not possible since the  has no id on it.

There are a few things you can do - either attach an id on your  tag and call getElementById() on that, which I don't recommend.

Or you can use the following to target the body by its tag name.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

Comment: _"which I don't recommend"_ Why not. An id is unique. A tag isn't. The browser can stop searching after the first result.

Comment: Note that `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. Instead I would recommend using [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body), which is a standardized property.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers were a bit lacking I decided to give you a complete answer.

First, you should look at how you're trying to get the elements since it's the most obvious one.

When trying to get an element by its tag name, you need to use `document.getElementsByTagName`, however like the name implies you will get several results instead of one, and the result will be a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

However, the simplest way would be to add an id to your heading.

```html
<h1 id="heading">Change the background color!</h1>
```

What about body? No need to use id's you can access body with:

```
const body = document.body
```

Next it's really recommended to load your script after the page has done loading, so place your script file at the end of the body tag, like so:

```html
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

You could use defer, read up on it here [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

## **Next, let's look at your javascript**

---

The first rule of javascript, unless you know what you're doing, **never use var**, use `let` or `const` instead.

- `const` for constants
- `let` for variables that will have a value re-assigned

Instead of using `var` to you save the colors, you can use let, since you will be re-assigning them later like so:

```
let backgroundColor = null
let headingColor = null
```

Notice, I'm also renaming your variables

As for the elements, you don't need to get their dom reference every time, instead, save them in a constant since you **don't want** them to change.

```
const body = document.body
const colorInput = document.getElementById('color')
const h1 = document.getElementById('heading')
```

Notice how we're using `document.getElementById()` and `document.body`

Last but not least, all you need to do now is assign the color variables with the current value of the `colorInput`

And then apply it to the style of the referenced elements in `saveColors()`

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
    backgroundColor = colorInput.value
}

function changeHeaderColor() {
    headingColor = colorInput.value
}

function saveColors() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  h1.style.backgroundColor = headingColor
}
```

## Code

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Change the background color!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="heading">Change the background color!</h1>
    <input type="color" id="color" value="#1784b3" /><br />
    <button onclick="changeBackgroundColor();">Save background color</button>
    <button onclick="changeHeaderColor();">Save header color</button>
    <button onclick="saveColors();">Apply changes to page</button>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
const body = document.body
const colorInput = document.getElementById('color')
const h1 = document.getElementById('heading')

let backgroundColor = null
let headingColor = null

function changeBackgroundColor() {
    backgroundColor = colorInput.value
}

function changeHeaderColor() {
    headingColor = colorInput.value
}

function saveColors() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  h1.style.backgroundColor = headingColor
}
```